# Stuck with Npm? npm install errors

Tags: npm, ubuntu-14.04, npm-install

I am having a strange problem with npm in my **ubuntu 14.04**. I have a package.json file in my project directory. when i try to run

```
npm install
```

it fails. It logs something like

```
 is related to insufficient space on your system.
```

But i have checked that there is enough available space in my directory. 
Here is the log

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/rafi/.npm/core-js/1.2.6/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/rafi/.npm/caniuse-db/1.0.30000384/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-49-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /home/rafi/Desktop/dsf.angular/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/modules/library/es6.object.to-string.js
npm ERR! code ENOSPC
npm ERR! errno -28

npm ERR! nospc ENOSPC, open '/home/rafi/Desktop/dsf.angular/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/modules/library/es6.object.to-string.js'
npm ERR! nospc This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! nospc and is related to insufficient space on your system.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Any idea what may be the problem here ?

Comment: What's the output of  `df -h /home/rafi`?

Comment: 3.47 GB left out of 19 GB.

Comment: and what about `df -h /tmp`?